# .clone().appendTo - Replace element styles not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, appendto

I have individual three arrows. on click; I want the div below them (letsChat) to change styles and I want to clone and append relevant information in that div. I also want it to revert back to it's original state when it is clicked again or if orientation is changed to portrait.

```js
document.querySelector('#compositionArrow').onclick = function(){
  var letsChat = document.querySelector('.lets-chat');
  var letsChatButton = document.querySelector('.lets-chat a');
  var compositionArrow = document.querySelector('#compositionArrow')
  var compositionText = document.querySelector('.composition-text');

    if (letsChatButton.style.display='flex' && window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
        
      compositionArrow.style.transform='rotate(180deg)';

      //letsChat.appendChild(compositionText).cloneNode(true);
      //compositionText.clone().appendTo.letsChat; return false;
      document.querySelector('.composition-text').clone().appendTo(document.querySelector('.lets-chat'));
      letsChat.style.background='#00BCD4';
      letsChatButton.style.display='none';
    }
    
    else if (letsChatButton.style.display='none' || window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches){ 
      
      compositionArrow.style.transform='rotate(180deg)';

      letsChat.style.background='#ff8f00';
      letsChatButton.style.display='flex';
    }
}
```

example can be found below: (you may have to play with window

[artpenleystudios.com](http://artpenleystudios.com)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that demonstrates part of what you asked.  It doesn't take into account orientation change, but it handles the click part.  As far as I know, there's no straightforward way to detect orientation change, but [here's an article that talks about a few options](https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change).  Another idea would be to use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) as it fires *orientationchange* events.

So after much back and forth and after looking at your site more closely, this is what I managed to cobble together.

```
jQuery('#compositionArrow').click(function() {

  var $letsChat = jQuery('.lets-chat');
  var letsChat = $letsChat[0];
  var letsChatButton = $letsChat.find('a')[0];

  // Remove old composition text if it exists.
  $letsChat.find('.composition-text').remove();

  if (letsChatButton.style.display !== 'none' && window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {

    this.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';

    $letsChat.append(jQuery('.composition-text').clone());
    letsChat.style.background = '#00BCD4';
    letsChatButton.style.display = 'none';
  }

  else if (letsChatButton.style.display === 'none' || window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {

    this.style.transform = '';

    letsChat.style.background = '#ff8f00';
    letsChatButton.style.display = 'flex';
  }

});
```

It works for me in FireFox on a downloaded version of your site.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I need, except on mine debug comes up with "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" and doesn't work? I tried relinking jQuery and then it just did nothing?! so strange

Comment: @ArtPenley - Interesting.  The web site you linked seems to be including jQuery.  Maybe something else is overriding **$**.  I have updated my code snippet (above) to compensate for this.  If that still doesn't work, I'll convert it back to plain JavaScript.  Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it, it's still not working? it's not even giving any errors? just nothing is happening?

Comment: @ArtPenley: At this point, I'd probably need to see the exact code you're working with in order to continue helping.  Is the link to your website (that you provided above) the most recent code?

Comment: Hi, yes the link is up to date, the code you provided is in it, I've been playing around with it but I'm totally stumped, in not very experienced with JavaScript and I'm fairly new to Wordpress too

Comment: @ArtPenley: After playing around with your website locally, I think I managed to hack together something that'll work.  I updated my answer above.  Good luck!